# Better way to display and differentiate scatter points?

Tags: matplotlib, scatter-plot

Bellow is the code I used to plot 4 different scatter data points. I am trying to find a way to better display the red and blue points so that they can easily be shown apart since they overlap each other and mix colors. I tried adjusting the transparency but its not really helping differentiating the blue from the red points.

```
sca1=a1.scatter(loglumha, logbhmass, color="black")
sca2=a1.scatter(clumerg, c2,  alpha=1.0, color="red")
sca3=a1.scatter(mlumerg, m2, alpha=0.6, color="blue")
sca4=a1.scatter(gh1, gh2, alpha=1.0, color="green")

a1.legend([sca1, sca2, sca3, sca4], ["Our Data", "Coziol et al., 2011", "Mendel et al., 2014", "Greene & Ho, 2007"])
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe change the marker to something less solid like a cross or a star?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use different [markers](http://matplotlib.org/api/markers_api.html). It will make it both easier for you and possible at all to for colorblind people.